# Iterate 2x2 tables and fishers exact over multiple columns in large dataframe in R

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, p-value

I'm new to [r](/questions/tagged/r) and I'm looking for help with looping and iterating over a large data frame to create multiple 2x2 tables with the `table()` function, followed by `fishers.test()` on each table to export the odds ratio and [p-value](/questions/tagged/p-value)s. 
My [dataframe](/questions/tagged/dataframe)s have cluster(s) and genes as columns like this:

```
**df**
Tag  Cluster  Gene1  Gene2  Gene3  Gene4
1    a        1      0      0      1
2    b        0      1      1      1
3    c        1      1      0      0  
4    d        0      0      0      1
5    e        1      1      0      0
```

The is the code I want iterated and looped.

```
tab<-table(df$Cluster =="a", df$Gene1)
fisher.test(tab)
```

I'm not sure where to begin and would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

P.S my actually data frame dimensions are 1010 x 191

Comment: Are you checking for all 'Gene' columns with `Cluster == 'a'`

Comment: Thanks, i made the correction. It's supposed to be df$Cluster =='a'

Answer (score 0):

If we are interested to do the `fisher.test` in all the 'Gene' column by using the same condition on 'Cluster'

```
library(dplyr)
out <-  df %>% 
            summarise_at(vars(starts_with('Gene')), ~ 
                list(table(Cluster == 'a', .) %>% 
               fisher.test))
out$Gene1
out$Gene2
```

---

In `base R`, this can be done with `lapply`

```
out2 <- lapply(df[startsWith(names(df), "Gene")], function(v) 
           fisher.test(table(df$Cluster == "a", v)))
out2$Gene1
out2$Gene2
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Tag = 1:5, Cluster = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
), Gene1 = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L), Gene2 = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L
), Gene3 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Gene4 = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I want to create the 2X2 tables for all 'Cluster' rows and all 'Gene' columns and do fishers test on all tables. I interested in seeing which genes are enriched in each of the clusters if that a better way of explaining.

Comment: @TAT_28 this is based on the code you showed in your post